# How do you escape Restrained condition?

Tags: dnd-4e, conditions

How do you escape the Restrained condition?

Comment: Can you give some more information? Are you looking for items that help you with this, or escaping from a specific monster, or just general information on the Restrained condition? This is not answerable right now.

Answer (score 2):

**It depends on how you were restrained.**

Whatever power inflicted the restrained condition on you should indicate how it ends. Until you save against the condition or until the end of the next turn of whoever inflicted restrained on you are by far the most common durations, but others are possible.

Note that you always know the details of a power that affects you, so if your DM isn't telling you when the condition will end, s/he is doing it wrong.